# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'copy'. Worked in 3.6, fails in 3.7

Tags: python

Code extract:

```
toMatrix  = [0.0] * NumBoth  #Establish dimensions
for i in range(NumBoth):
    toMatrix [i] = [0.0] * NumBoth
for indx in iter(range(NumSvcDep,NumBoth)):
    toMatrix [indx][indx] = 1.0
print(type(toMatrix),type(fromMatrix))
fromMatrix = toMatrix.copy()
```

If context matters, I'm setting a matrix to "0"s except for part of the diagonal set to "1"s. While I'd love to hear better ways to do that, my main problem if doing the copy. This ran on V3.6 but fails on v3.7. I'm pretty sure the code hasn't been changed but it's been awhile.

Comment: What error is getting thrown? What are your inputs and expected outputs? Add those, if applicable, to your question.

Comment: Does `import copy; fromMatrix = copy.deepcopy(toMatrix)` work?

Answer (score 3):

Deep copy of list works a little different:

```
fromMatrix = toMatrix[:]
```

should solve your error, Alternatively, you can do:

```
fromMatrix = list(toMatrix)
```

Answer (score 2):

According to docs, `copy` is still supported in 3.7 [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Also, I have a 3.7 on my machine and the `copy` works fine. (Are you sure 3.7 and not 2.7? :O just asking)

Any way, it's equivalent to the selector `[:]`

> list.copy()
>
> Return a shallow copy of the list. Equivalent to [:].

```
fromMatrix = toMatrix[:]
```